# extends 'base.html' doesn't work in django

Tags: django, templates, extends

my base.html code -

```
<html>

<body bgcolor="cyan">

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

my home.html code-

```
<% extends 'base.html' %>

<% block content %>

<h1>Hello {{name}}!!!</h1>

<% endblock %>
```

django server output

```
<% extends 'base.html' %> <% block content %>
Hello viraj!!!
<% endblock %>
```

home.html and base.html are in the same directory.

Comment: You assume `<%` means anything to Django, but it only means something to ASP. Use `{%`.

Comment: which directory? are those exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You use curly braces, not angled braces.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h1>Hello {{name}}!!!</h1>

{% endblock %}
```